# How Can I Compare and Hold Some Value : SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server

I have a table looks like this:

```
ITEM    |   DATE    |  PRICE | NEW_PRICE | REDUCTION |
Pencil  | 01/10/14  |    25  |    21     |     4     |
Pencil  | 01/12/14  |    21  |    21     |     0     |
Pencil  | 01/30/14  |    21  |    21     |     0     |
Pencil  | 02/05/14  |    21  |    18     |     3     |
Pencil  | 02/17/14  |    18  |    18     |     0     |
Pencil  | 03/20/14  |    18  |    18     |     0     |
Pencil  | 06/08/14  |    18  |    16     |     2     |
Pencil  | 07/14/14  |    16  |    16     |     0     |
Pencil  | 07/28/14  |    16  |    16     |     0     |
```

How can I select so I can get the result like this:

```
ITEM    |   DATE    |  PRICE | NEW_PRICE | REDUCTION | REDUCTION_HOLD |
Pencil  | 01/10/14  |    25  |    21     |     4     |       4        |
Pencil  | 01/12/14  |    21  |    21     |     0     |       4        |
Pencil  | 01/30/14  |    21  |    21     |     0     |       4        |
Pencil  | 02/05/14  |    21  |    18     |     3     |       3        |
Pencil  | 02/17/14  |    18  |    18     |     0     |       3        |
Pencil  | 03/20/14  |    18  |    18     |     0     |       3        |
Pencil  | 06/08/14  |    18  |    16     |     2     |       2        |
Pencil  | 07/14/14  |    16  |    16     |     0     |       2        |
Pencil  | 07/28/14  |    16  |    16     |     0     |       2        |
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a sub query:

```
SELECT ITEM = 'Pencil', DATE = '01/10/14', PRICE  = 25, NEW_PRICE = 21 , REDUCTION = 4 INTO #Table
UNION ALL SELECT 'Pencil'   ,'01/12/14'      ,21      ,21         ,0
UNION ALL SELECT 'Pencil'   ,'01/30/14'      ,21      ,21         ,0
UNION ALL SELECT 'Pencil'   ,'02/05/14'      ,21      ,18         ,3
UNION ALL SELECT 'Pencil'   ,'02/17/14'      ,18      ,18         ,0
UNION ALL SELECT 'Pencil'   ,'03/20/14'      ,18      ,18         ,0
UNION ALL SELECT 'Pencil'   ,'06/08/14'      ,18      ,16         ,2
UNION ALL SELECT 'Pencil'   ,'07/14/14'      ,16      ,16         ,0
UNION ALL SELECT 'Pencil'   ,'07/28/14'      ,16      ,16         ,0

GO

SELECT * 
, REDUCTION_HOLD = (SELECT TOP 1 REDUCTION FROM #Table b WHERE a.DATE >= b.DATE AND b.REDUCTION > 0 ORDER BY b.DATE DESC)
FROM #Table a ORDER BY DATE
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Working like a Charm, Mr.Bjørnbeth, You Saved my day! Thank You ! :D